# How To Extract Page URLs From Any Website in Bulk?

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, scraper, extractor

I'm looking for a Free solution/tool/software through which I can pull out all of the website's page URLs. Site has approx 992,000 pages so I need the URLs of all of them in excel sheet.

I'm using "**site: mywebsite.com**" and it gives me 992,000 results. I know I can make the max results per page 100 but that still doesn't make my life easier. Also google won't show any results over 1000. Tried to use the **Google API** but without any luck. Tried **Sitemap Generators** but they didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a crawler tool to crawl the entire website and save the URLs visited.  Free tools include:

- IRobotSoft: http://www.irobotsoft.com/help/irobot-manual.pdf.  Use: CrawlWebsite (SourceSites, CallTask) function.
- Scrapy: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Google limits search query results to 1000. The only way a tool could really bypass this is to do subsets of the keyword e.g. (site: abc.com + random-word). The random word would return fewer results and with enough of these queries scraped and combined into a list, one could then delete duplicates and gain a near-full to full list of the original desired search term.

Comment: It wouldn't work; as I can't afford to miss even a single URL.